# select rows mysql where the value of the left join is different

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `messages` and a table `deleted_messages` every time the delete action on a message is fired instead delete the record I create a new record on the `deleted_messages` table. Then i would like retrieve the messages without the deleted messages on the `deleted_messages`.

**ps**: I don't use soft delete here because a lots of users can delete the messages for they self but not for the others users

My schema:

**users table**

```
id | name
```

**messages table**

```
id | user_id | message
```

**deleted_messages**

```
id | message_id | user_id
```

The query that i'm trying to perform to get all messages of the user 1 without the deleted messages is the following but it return 0 rows:

```
select *
from messages 
left join deleted_messages on deleted_messages.message_id = messages.id
where deleted_messages.user_id != 1
```

Take a look [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2e3/2) it should get 2 messages but it return null.

Comment: May I suggest using a anti-join here instead? `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM y)`

Comment: what do you mean with anti-join? :), oh i see but 2 queries as more slower than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
select *
from messages m
left join deleted_messages d on d.message_id = m.id
where 
 d.message_id IS NULL
AND m.user_id = 1
```

This will give all the messages from user 1 which are not deleted

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2e3/14)

Other way to use  `NOT EXISTS`

```
select *
from messages m
where not exists
(select 1 from deleted_messages d where d.message_id = m.id)
AND m.user_id = 1
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2e3/24)

For performance factor you can find the details here
[**LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns**](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888)

Comment: Woo it seem to work I'll try now on my code and I'll let you know :) thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lots, you suggest me to use the second one?

Comment: @Fabrizio yes `NOT EXISTS` approach is like faster in some scenarios as compared to left join

Comment: Thanks a lots! for the answer really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

add the were condition in the left join clause

```
select *
from messages 
left join deleted_messages on deleted_messages.message_id = messages.id
and  deleted_messages.user_id = 1
where deleted_messages.message_id is  null
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2e3/17)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages m
WHERE m.user_id = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted_messages dm where dm.message_id = m.id)
```

But if you need to use `left join`, this should also work:

```
SELECT m.*, dm.message_id FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN deleted_messages dm ON dm.message_id = m.message_id
WHERE m.user_id = 1
AND message_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to move the condition into the *join* condition and look for *missed* joins in there where clause:

```
select messages.*
from messages 
left join deleted_messages on deleted_messages.message_id = messages.id
and deleted_messages.user_id != 1 -- condition here still allows left join
where deleted_messages.user_id is null -- filters out hits
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2e3/28)

Comment: @Fabrizio sorry - i hadn't finished. what were you expecting? see sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try With This.

```
select * from messages left join deleted_messages on deleted_messages.user_id = messages.user_id where deleted_messages.user_id != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.*
from messages m
left join deleted_messages dm
   on dm.message_id = m.id
where dm.user_id is null
  and m.user_id = 1
```